# About jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best utilization for multiple jquery selector ?

```
jQuery(this) / jQuery('#id')
```

or

```
var _this = jQuery(this)
```

?

Comment: What?? add some clearer explanation about what you mean

Comment: I need just the best method between call jQuery('#id') and save this into a variable ? sorry for my little english

Comment: The selector you should use really depends on many different factors, like your html design first, the place where you want to access and so on. If you want an answer you should first explain your case in a more detailed way, so we can advice.

Comment: Yep sorry guy i dont have word in english for explain that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main diff between

```
jQuery('#id');
```

and

```
var selector = jQuery('#id');
```

for first type, if you are calling the same thing more than one time than for each call there is DOM traverse to get the element reference,
but in second case it saves the reference and do not traverse DOM for each request. This saves the overhead.

Comment: Ah thanks you its exactly what i need. Thanks Pandeyz